# $script.js nested dependencies

Tags: javascript, dynamic-script-loading

Is there a way to make the following work with $script.js:

**control.js**

```
$script('accounts.js', function() {
    // fnA
});
```

**accounts.js**

```
$script('util.js', function() {
    // fnB
});
```

I would have hoped that `fnB` is executed before `fnA`, but it's not. Therefore, namespaces and objects created in `fnB` are not available to `fnA`, namely the accounts functionality.

**util.js** contains only a namespace function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do this:

```
control.js
$script('util.js', function() {
    // fnB
    $script('accounts.js', function() {
       // fnA
    });
});
```

And it wouldn't be necessary for `accounts.js` to load `utils.js`.

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks @Edgar. I also read that nesting isnt required so you can have: $script('util.js', 'util'); $script('accounts.js', 'accounts'); $script.ready('accounts', function() { fnA });

Comment: to avoid race conditions you also need to have inside accounts.js: $script.ready('util', function...);